# UWP Media Element Custom control giving exception

Tags: xaml, custom-controls, win-universal-app, sample, mediaelement

I am having a very strange situation over here.
I refered to the UWP samples and tried Custom Media transport controls sample. I ran it and it was working just fine, like its supposed to work. But then I tried and made my own project and I copied exactly everything which was in sample project not even name of file or folder was different. And then when I ran that project it gave me debugger unhandled exception and open App.ig.cs   some file like this and when i continue it stop debugging. Below is the attached snapshot of that error. Any help is appreciated this is a really strange error for me as it makes no sense at all.
Note: I have tried to run it in both blend and visual studio

[image]

Comment: What type of exception (in 'e')?

Comment: solved it see my answer, but thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by simply ignoring the style of transport controls provided in the sample, for some reason that style was not able to verify some properties so I deleted that file and made my own style file, I copied the style of default media controls and edited them, it worked for me :)